# C++ object design

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have:

```
// file model.h
#include "instrument.h"
class model
{
    // A function which uses instruments and returns double.
    double value(Instrument instruments);
}
```

Now in file instrument.h

```
// file instrument.h
class Instrument
{
    // This function needs to use model.
    double value2(model* md);
}
```

Now in file `instrument.h`, should I be using `#include "model.h"`? That kind of seems like a bad design.

How do I design this two object Instrument and model so that they know and can use each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Forward declarations:*

```
class Instrument;
class model
{
  // function which uses instruments and returns double
  double value(Instrument instruments);
};

//...

class model;
class Instrument
{
  // function needs to use model
  double value2(model* md); 
}
```

If your class doesn't contain data members of the other type, you don't need the full definition of the type. For example, if you have a member pointer, function return values or, like in your case, parameters.

Also, your intuition is correct. You should keep `include`s in header files to a minimum. Headers should be self-contained, but not have unnecessary headers.

Comment: Good answer. `Instrument` parameter of `value` method should also be a pointer, since it's now an incomplete type.

Comment: @Macmade no. For parameters you don't need a complete type.

Comment: @Luchian: For functions you don't call.

Comment: @DeadMG if you call the function, you need the complete type to construct the parameter. But that's a completely different reason...